# install Ubuntu Openstack Autopilot on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS via conjure-up

Tags: openstack-autopilot

All environment Lab has been realised on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

- 1 VM for MAAS
- 1 VM for JUJU
- 1 VM for LANDSCAPE
- 5 VM for OPENSTACK

The initial situation is the following

[image]

running the conjure command as suggest from official guide

```
$: conjure-up --bootstrap-to nodeJuju
```

conjure begins the deploy

[image]

but after the vm is deployed

[image]

I receive this error:

[image]

I've pasted the conjure-up.log here (https://paste.ubuntu.com/24328008/), at the end of that there is this error:

*

```
2017-04-06 14:43:54 ERROR cmd supercommand.go:458 new environ: Authorization Error: 'Expired timestamp: given 1491489833 and now 1491497374 has a greater difference than threshold
 300'
```

*

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution has been to set a correct time clock on my virtual environment, in this way all vm have worked with the same clock of MAAS Server. 
[here](https://github.com/conjure-up/conjure-up/issues/803) the post